# loading specific file from amazon-s3

Tags: matlab, amazon-s3

say I create filedatastore object by

```
fds = fileDatastore(bucket, "ReadFcn", @load, 'IncludeSubfolders', true,...
'FileExtensions', '.mat');
```

Then I can read the found files according to their order. My question: How to read the Nth file from the list of fds.Files without creating a new filedatastore object (communicating with s3)?

Comment: Hello, are you still struggling with this?

Comment: I did not solve it. I consider overcoming it using the command line package...

Comment: I am back from vacation so I can take a look. What MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2019a

Comment: My bad for suggesting `read(fds.Files{1})`, that will not work as *read* expects a fileDatastore object. To answer your question, it looks like this isn't possible, as *read* does not seem to support indexing. Your best bet is to *readall* on the fileDatastore object and then index into the result.

Comment: Thanks. That would not help me for parallel processing, right?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
fds = fileDatastore('s3://bucketname/path/file.mat', "ReadFcn", @load);
```